# bash: how to pass password containing special characters

Tags: bash, shell, special-characters

I have a bash script to download data from a website. For this I need to pass the username and password using a java client for the website. My password has a special character that is causing problems. I have tried the usual solutions but none are working.

```
#!/bin/sh
#$ -cwd

MYPASSWORD='password&123'

java -jar client.jar -p username $MYPASSWORD file.gz
```

Tried using \ either directly in the command or using the variable. But that didnt work. Login failed!

```
MYPASSWORD=password\&123
java -jar client.jar -p username $MYPASSWORD file.gz
```

Tried "" or ''. Login failure.

```
MYPASSWORD='password&123'
java -jar client.jar -p username "\"$MYPASSWORD\"" file.gz
```

Also tried it, no luck. 
    MYPASSWORD='password'"&"'123'

Any suggestions would be most helpful. Resetting the password on this website also seems problematic.

Comment: may try triple simple quote (''') for enclosing ?

Comment: Are you able to use this java program to download the file without a bash script? If the program doesn't work outside of a script, it will not work inside of a script.

Comment: What F4240 means is: did you try `${MYPASSWORD}` ?

Comment: What is this special character? A Newline? A NUL-Character?

Answer (score 4):

Just quote the parameter.

```
mypassword='password&123'
java -jar client.jar -p username "$mypassword" file.gz
```

The quotes are only there to keep the shell from performing any further processing of the *value* of `mypassword` after the parameter is expanded. You don't actually pass quotes to your program.

Comment: Then the problem isn't with the shell; you've either mistyped the password, or the Java program is mishandling it internally.

Comment: (The only other case would be if your password contains a single quote, which can't be included in a single-quoted string: `foo='bob'spassword'` doesn't set `foo` to `bob'spass'word`, but to the concatenation of the quoted string `bob` and the unquoted string `spass`, and the unquoted string `word`).

Comment: Maybe because your shebang is `/bin/sh` instead of `/bin/bash`.

Comment: @Kenavoz No. The code I posted contains no `bash` extensions.

Comment: I am sure the password is correct since I can login interactively and that doesnt have a problem. I just need to run 400 jobs and so cant run it in interactive mode. Also no single quotes in the password. And have tried both     /bin/sh instead of      /bin/bash and removed it entirely too. Could be a problem due to java...any suggestions how to pass special chars in java?

Comment: The special characters *are* passed to Java. The question is, what does your Java program do with that data? (Rhetorical question; you'll have to post a new question if you want to dig into your Java code.)

Comment: How did you determine that the problem is a special character and not general invocation? Are you sure `-p username password filename` is the correct syntax? That it's not `-p username@password filename` or `-u username -p password` or anything like that? Also, check your script for carriage returns.

Comment: The download, format, password etc work interactively and so I dont think thats the problem. @chepner: Its not my java problem but an executable provided by the download website and so cant really debug that. Could def. be the source of the problem.